# How JPA or Hibernate generate UUID as key?

Tags: mysql, hibernate, jpa, mybatis, uuid

I am trying to use UUID as key with Mybatis. There are usually two ways:

1. Generate user keys in code.
2. [Use `uuid()` method in mysql.](http://mysqlserverteam.com/storing-uuid-values-in-mysql-tables/)

The first soluation should be a better choice for me, my question is how to implement a method to generate UUID as keys as JPA or Hibernate does? Their UUID keys is not a standard UUID.

1. with no dash.
2. rearrange the sequence for better performance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used｀UUIDHexGenerator｀ from Hibernate to generate UUID now.

UUIDHexGenerator.java

```
/*
 * Hibernate, Relational Persistence for Idiomatic Java
 *
 * Copyright (c) 2008, Red Hat Middleware LLC or third-party contributors as
 * indicated by the @author tags or express copyright attribution
 * statements applied by the authors.  All third-party contributions are
 * distributed under license by Red Hat Middleware LLC.
 *
 * This copyrighted material is made available to anyone wishing to use, modify,
 * copy, or redistribute it subject to the terms and conditions of the GNU
 * Lesser General Public License, as published by the Free Software Foundation.
 *
 * This program is distributed in the hope that it will be useful,
 * but WITHOUT ANY WARRANTY; without even the implied warranty of MERCHANTABILITY
 * or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.  See the GNU Lesser General Public License
 * for more details.
 *
 * You should have received a copy of the GNU Lesser General Public License
 * along with this distribution; if not, write to:
 * Free Software Foundation, Inc.
 * 51 Franklin Street, Fifth Floor
 * Boston, MA  02110-1301  USA
 *
 */

import java.io.Serializable;


/**
 * <b>uuid</b><br>
 * <br>
 * A <tt>UUIDGenerator</tt> that returns a string of length 32,
 * This string will consist of only hex digits. Optionally,
 * the string may be generated with separators between each
 * component of the UUID.
 *
 * Mapping parameters supported: separator.
 *
 * @author Gavin King
 */

public class UUIDHexGenerator extends AbstractUUIDGenerator {

    private String sep = "";

    protected String format(int intval) {
        String formatted = Integer.toHexString(intval);
        StringBuffer buf = new StringBuffer("00000000");
        buf.replace( 8-formatted.length(), 8, formatted );
        return buf.toString();
    }

    protected String format(short shortval) {
        String formatted = Integer.toHexString(shortval);
        StringBuffer buf = new StringBuffer("0000");
        buf.replace( 4-formatted.length(), 4, formatted );
        return buf.toString();
    }

    public Serializable generate() {
        return new StringBuffer(36)
            .append( format( getIP() ) ).append(sep)
            .append( format( getJVM() ) ).append(sep)
            .append( format( getHiTime() ) ).append(sep)
            .append( format( getLoTime() ) ).append(sep)
            .append( format( getCount() ) )
            .toString();
    }

    public static void main( String[] args ) throws Exception {
        UUIDHexGenerator gen = new UUIDHexGenerator();
        UUIDHexGenerator gen2 = new UUIDHexGenerator();

        for ( int i=0; i<100; i++) {
            String id = (String) gen.generate();
            System.out.println(id);
            String id2 = (String) gen2.generate();
            System.out.println(id2);
            String id3 = (String) gen2.generate();
            System.out.println(id3);
        }

    }

}
```

BytesHelper.java

```
/*
 * Hibernate, Relational Persistence for Idiomatic Java
 *
 * Copyright (c) 2008, Red Hat Middleware LLC or third-party contributors as
 * indicated by the @author tags or express copyright attribution
 * statements applied by the authors.  All third-party contributions are
 * distributed under license by Red Hat Middleware LLC.
 *
 * This copyrighted material is made available to anyone wishing to use, modify,
 * copy, or redistribute it subject to the terms and conditions of the GNU
 * Lesser General Public License, as published by the Free Software Foundation.
 *
 * This program is distributed in the hope that it will be useful,
 * but WITHOUT ANY WARRANTY; without even the implied warranty of MERCHANTABILITY
 * or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.  See the GNU Lesser General Public License
 * for more details.
 *
 * You should have received a copy of the GNU Lesser General Public License
 * along with this distribution; if not, write to:
 * Free Software Foundation, Inc.
 * 51 Franklin Street, Fifth Floor
 * Boston, MA  02110-1301  USA
 *
 */

public final class BytesHelper {

    private BytesHelper() {}

    public static int toInt( byte[] bytes ) {
        int result = 0;
        for (int i=0; i<4; i++) {
            result = ( result << 8 ) - Byte.MIN_VALUE + (int) bytes[i];
        }
        return result;
    }

}
```

AbstractUUIDGenerator.java

```
/*
 * Hibernate, Relational Persistence for Idiomatic Java
 *
 * Copyright (c) 2008, Red Hat Middleware LLC or third-party contributors as
 * indicated by the @author tags or express copyright attribution
 * statements applied by the authors.  All third-party contributions are
 * distributed under license by Red Hat Middleware LLC.
 *
 * This copyrighted material is made available to anyone wishing to use, modify,
 * copy, or redistribute it subject to the terms and conditions of the GNU
 * Lesser General Public License, as published by the Free Software Foundation.
 *
 * This program is distributed in the hope that it will be useful,
 * but WITHOUT ANY WARRANTY; without even the implied warranty of MERCHANTABILITY
 * or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.  See the GNU Lesser General Public License
 * for more details.
 *
 * You should have received a copy of the GNU Lesser General Public License
 * along with this distribution; if not, write to:
 * Free Software Foundation, Inc.
 * 51 Franklin Street, Fifth Floor
 * Boston, MA  02110-1301  USA
 *
 */
import java.net.InetAddress;

/**
 * The base class for identifier generators that use a UUID algorithm. This
 * class implements the algorithm, subclasses define the identifier
 * format.
 *
 * @see UUIDHexGenerator
 * @author Gavin King
 */

public abstract class AbstractUUIDGenerator {

    private static final int IP;
    static {
        int ipadd;
        try {
            ipadd = BytesHelper.toInt( InetAddress.getLocalHost().getAddress() );
        }
        catch (Exception e) {
            ipadd = 0;
        }
        IP = ipadd;
    }
    private static short counter = (short) 0;
    private static final int JVM = (int) ( System.currentTimeMillis() >>> 8 );

    public AbstractUUIDGenerator() {
    }

    /**
     * Unique across JVMs on this machine (unless they load this class
     * in the same quater second - very unlikely)
     */
    protected int getJVM() {
        return JVM;
    }

    /**
     * Unique in a millisecond for this JVM instance (unless there
     * are > Short.MAX_VALUE instances created in a millisecond)
     */
    protected short getCount() {
        synchronized(AbstractUUIDGenerator.class) {
            if (counter<0) counter=0;
            return counter++;
        }
    }

    /**
     * Unique in a local network
     */
    protected int getIP() {
        return IP;
    }

    /**
     * Unique down to millisecond
     */
    protected short getHiTime() {
        return (short) ( System.currentTimeMillis() >>> 32 );
    }
    protected int getLoTime() {
        return (int) System.currentTimeMillis();
    }


}
```